# Translate SQL to BQL in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I want to translate from *SQL*

```
select * from table where table.field in('A','B')
```

to Acumatica *BQL*.

Please help me to get this info.

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways to do that:

**1. Using In3/Or and BQL constants**

First thing you'll need to do is create BQL constants representing 'A' and 'B'.
Like that:

```
public class constantA: PX.Data.Constant<string>
{
    public constantA() : base("A") { }
}
public class constantB: PX.Data.Constant<string>
{
    public constantB() : base("B") { }
}
```

This will allow you to use A and B in your BQL query. (You can find more info about that in T200 Training, Example 3.1: Providing Data for the Inquiry Page)
(you can use `PX.Data.Constant<int>`, `PX.Data.Constant<decimal>`, etc. depending on parameter type)

After that you can compose BQL:

```
PXSelect<Table, Where<Table.field, In3<constantA, constantB>>>
```

(or  `PXSelect<Table, Where<Table.field, Equal<constantA>, Or<Table.field, Equal<constantB>>>>`)

**2. Using In and Required**

```
PXSelect<Table, Where<Table.field, In<Required<Table.field>>>>.Select(graph, new string[]{"A","B"}) //you may need to use array of objects instead of array of strings
```

this way allows you to compose list of constants at runtime and pass it like a parameter to the query. Parameter should be array of the corresponding type(it's strings array in this example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `PX.Data.Constant<T>` is deprecated now.

Need to use the following:

```
public class constantA : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<constantA>
{
    public constantA() : base("A") { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Select only ONE item where field="A". field="B" exist

```
    var arr = new string[]{"A","B"};

    PXSelect<Table, Where<Table.field, In<Required<Table.field>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), arr ,**arr**)
```

It happened, but why?
Thanks.