# Acumatica - BQL Select table field where equals string

Tags: c#, acumatica

I would like to select any fields in my SQL table that are equal with the specified test string in my code. I have seen this post: [Translate SQL to BQL in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316528/translate-sql-to-bql-in-acumatica) however, this is done via constants which is immutable. Ideally, I would like to change the string via a combo box. This is what I have:

```
  public class TestOverview : PXGraph<TestOverview, TestOverview.MasterTable>
  {
       string test = "USA"

       public PXSelect<DemoCustomerBreakdown, 
       Where<DemoCustomerBreakdown.countryRegion,
       Equal<"I would like my string to go here">> CustomerCountry;
  }
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this without using a constant class? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to bind this view to a form view, a constant is your only option. If on the other hand you want to use this view to select data from your code, you can use the Required<> operand and then pass the string when you select from this view:

```
 PXSelect<DemoCustomerBreakdown, 
   Where<DemoCustomerBreakdown.countryRegion,
   Equal<Required<DemoCustomerBreakdown.countryRegion>>> CustomerCountry;

 var results = CustomerCountry.Select(this, “My string”);
```